# I am getting a SQL syntax error - how to fix it?

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting a syntax error in this SQL:

```
select * 
from messages 
where date > (select lastinterval from messageintervals 
              order by lastinterval desc 
              limit 1)
```

What is my mistake? Help me please

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, you should use `TOP` instead of `LIMIT`.

```
select *  
from messages 
where date > (select top 1 lastinterval 
              from messageintervals 
              order by lastinterval desc)
```

Comment: Read the first sentence again - mssql uses `TOP`, not `LIMIT`.